# Add two timestamps of format "HH+:MM:SS"

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp

So basically i have two strings of timestamps which i want to add:

```
a = "00:10:12";
aParts = a.split(/:/);  

b = "00:30:34";
bParts = b.split(/:/);  

time1 = 3600000 * parseInt(aParts[0]) + 60000 * parseInt(aParts[1]) + 1000 * parseInt(aParts[2]);
time2 = 3600000 * parseInt(bParts[0]) + 60000 * parseInt(bParts[1]) + 1000 * parseInt(bParts[2]);

dateTime = time1 + time2;

hours = parseInt(dateTime/3600000);
dateTime = parseInt(dateTime%3600000);

minutes = parseInt(dateTime/60000);
dateTime = parseInt(dateTime%60000);

seconds = parseInt(dateTime/1000);

newTime = addLeadingZeros(hours,2) + ':' + addLeadingZeros(minutes,2) + ':' + addLeadingZeros(seconds,2);

// returns correct "00:40:46"

function addLeadingZeros (n, length){
   var str = (n > 0 ? n : -n) + "";
   var zeros = "";
   for (var i = length - str.length; i > 0; i--)
     zeros += "0";
   zeros += str;
   return n >= 0 ? zeros : "-" + zeros;
}
```

While writing this question i managed to come up with the above code :-) that works somehow - is that a proper way of adding two string timestamps or is there a better approach?

Forgot to mention - i did try converting the two strings into Date objects and using .getTime() adding the two datetimes - but that gives me a wrong time in the date.

Comment: why are you using regular time format, why don't u use `new Date().getTime();` that returns the time in milliseconds ?

Comment: Forgot to mention - i did try converting the two strings into Date objects and using .getTime() adding the two datetimes - but that gives me a wrong time in the date.

Comment: of course it will, you are adding two different times (including the date),, you can filter out the date in one of them if you want to add them together example : `dateTime = time1 + time2%216000000; /* returns the milliseconds of the time part only (1000*60*60*60).*/`

Comment: imo your code is all right, only [to prevent possibly wrong results always specify the default radix 10 for parseInt() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_Interpretations_with_No_Radix).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing notably wrong with your code, but be sure to set the `radix` when using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

> **radix**
>
> An integer that represents the radix of the value to parse. Always
>   specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion
>   and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations
>   produce different results when a radix is not specified.

There is no standard method for performing the task that you have described.

Here is an example that I have used in the past.

Javascript

```
/*jslint maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true, devel: true */

(function () {
    "use strict";

    function zeroPad(num) {
        var str = num.toString();

        if (num < 2) {
            str = "0" + str;
        }

        return str;
    }

    function addTimes() {
        if (!arguments.length) {
            throw new SyntaxError("No arguments provided.");
        }

        var total = {
                hours: 0,
                minutes: 0,
                seconds: 0
            },
            argIndex,
            argLength,
            time,
            parts,
            part,
            partIndex,
            temp;

        for (argIndex = 0, argLength = arguments.length; argIndex < argLength; argIndex += 1) {
            time = arguments[argIndex];
            if (typeof time !== "string") {
                throw new TypeError("Argument must be a string.");
            }

            parts = time.split(":");
            if (parts.length !== 3) {
                throw new SyntaxError("Argument is incorrectly formatted.");
            }

            for (partIndex = 0; partIndex < 3; partIndex += 1) {
                part = parts[partIndex];
                if (partIndex < 2) {
                    if (part === "" || !/^\d*$/.test(part)) {
                        throw new SyntaxError("Argument is incorrectly formatted.");
                    }

                    parts[partIndex] = parseInt(part, 10);
                } else {
                    if (part === "" || !/^\d*\.?\d+$/.test(part)) {
                        throw new SyntaxError("Argument is incorrectly formatted.");
                    }

                    parts[partIndex] = parseFloat(part);
                }
            }

            temp = (parts[2] + total.seconds);
            total.seconds = temp % 60;
            temp = (parts[1] + total.minutes) + (temp - total.seconds) / 60;
            total.minutes = temp % 60;
            total.hours = (parts[0] + total.hours) + (temp - total.minutes) / 60;
        }

        return zeroPad(total.hours) + ":" + zeroPad(total.minutes) + ":" + zeroPad(total.seconds);
    }

    var a = "00:10:12",
        b = "00:30:34",
        c = "10:40:40";

    console.log(addTimes(a, b, c));
}());
```

Output

```
11:21:26
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/qTrke/)